# connect by level scenario in Db2

Tags: db2

I have a scenario in DB2 where I have a column value as

select value from table where id='02346'

value

1,2,3,4,5,6,7

I want to convert this above value as below using DB2 query.

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

How can I achieve this? i

Using oracle its done as below.
with test as
(select '421907802490;421907672085;421911460415;421905464170;421907802292' col from dual)
select regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
from test
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^;]+')) + 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it as is.

```
select x.tok
from 
-- uncomment this and comment out "(values ...) t (id, value)"
-- table t
(
 values ('02346', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7')
) t (id, value)
, xmltable
(
  'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
  passing 
    t.value as "s"
  columns 
    tok varchar(4000) path '.'
) x
where t.id = '02346'
```

**Update**
If you are not at Db2 for LUW, you may use the same RCTE approach:

```
with 
-- Uncomment to run as is
/*
mytab (id, value) as 
(
  select '02346', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' from sysibm.sysdummy1
),
*/ 
cte (tok, value) as 
(
  select 
    substr (value, 1, coalesce (nullif (locate (',', value) - 1, -1), length (value)))
  , substr (value, nullif (locate (',', value) + 1, 1))
  from mytab
  where id = '02346' and length (value) <> 0
    union all 
  select 
    substr (value, 1, coalesce (nullif (locate (',', value) - 1, -1), length (value)))
  , substr (value, nullif (locate (',', value) + 1, 1))
  from cte
  where value is not null
)
select tok
from cte
```

The result is the same:

| TOK |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CTCEz5n9)

Comment: This does not work in DB2 SQL.  sQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "(". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: . <IDENTIFIER> JOIN INNER LEFT RIGHT FULL CROSS. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.29.24

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: db2 v12 / z/os mainframe

Comment: The updated query also did not work.  Using db2 v12 / z/os mainframe version. I am using dbeaver as the client.                                                                                                            SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "MYTAB". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: DSN_INLINE_OPT_HINT. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.29.24

Comment: Always specify your Db2 platform and version. zDb2 doesn't support `values ...`. The updated answer should work on zDb2. If you don't uncomment the commented out block, you must specify your real table instead of `mytab` of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on LUW, using a fairly recent version and can enable Oracle Compability Mode, your query works out of the box. Tried with:

```
[db2inst1@db2server ~]$ db2set
DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA


[db2inst1@db2server ~]$ db2 "with test as (select '421907802490;421907672085;421911460415;421905464170;421907802292' col from dual) select regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, level) result from test connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^;]+')) + 1"

RESULT                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------
421907802490                                                    
421907672085                                                    
421911460415                                                    
421905464170                                                    
421907802292                                                    

  5 record(s) selected.
```

Tested with:

```
sudo docker pull ibmcom/db2
sudo docker run ...
sudo docker exec -it db2server bash
su - db2inst1
```